# How to find average of a particular field of Mongo collection using MongoRepository in springboot?

Tags: mongodb, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have document structure in mongo collection as below:

```
{
  "_id": "jfnhnjgvdjnjegjefogj",
  "userId": "adfew"
   "rating": "2"
}
```

An userId can have multiple ratings. There are other userIds too. I want to calculate an average rating of a particular userId.
I have created Mongo repository as follows

```
public interface RatingDao extends MongoRepository<Rating , String> {
    @Aggregation(pipeline = { "{$group: { '_id': '$userId', rating: {$avg: $rating }}}" })
    double avg(String userId);
}
```

However, the above method is not correct.
I am not sure what will be correct approach. Please guide on this.

Rating Document POJO is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(value = "Rating")
public class Rating {
    private String userId;
    private int rating;
}
```

I am using below dependency in pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I am looking for a repository method where input will be the userId and it returns average.  I found many resources to do, however I am not able to find any simple approach to calculate average / any aggregate function for particular field of a collection.

Comment: The collection document has the field `"rating": "2"` - the type is a _string_. And you are working with an _integer_ in your Java code (including the aggregation). Try using same data types _or_ convert where applicable in your application.

Comment: Well, that was a typo. In DB rating is stored as int type only.

Comment: use ```?0``` instead of ```'$userId'``` in annotation